# What format is a Date in CoreData - Date or String?

Tags: core-data

I have a routine that compares when a record was last updated on a website with the same record saved in `CoreData` on an iPad. Here, **obsLastUpdated** is a field in CoreData set as type `Date`.

Reading the data from `CoreData` into an NSDate:

```
NSDate *iPadDate = [[self.recordDetails objectAtIndex:0] obsLastUpdated]; //gets the date from CoreData
```

I get this warning:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSDate *' with an expression
>   of type 'NSString *'

It is just a warning however and everything still works. If I try and compare this `NSDate` iPadDate with another `NSDate` there are no errors and everything works. But I would like to get to the bottom of the warning.

If I read from `CoreData` as a string and convert to an `NSDate` I can't seem to get the formatting correct and the app crashes. I have tried:

```
NSString *iPadDateStr = [[self.recordDetails objectAtIndex:0] obsLastUpdated];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *iPadDate = [dateFormat dateFromString: iPadDateStr];
```

I realise that `CoreData` does not store the date as an `NSDate` but how exactly is it stored and how do I get around the warning?

CoreData Entity:

[image]

UPDATE:

The error was in the class where obsLastUpdated was declared as an NSString. Changed to NSDate and all is well.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the core data model entity.

Comment: Then you have created the core data model to have a String. Not a Date. Can you show a screenshot of you core data mode. And include the object code also.

Comment: and the code for the class? Something is wrong. Show us what is wrong. Not what is right. :-) when you set an attribute as a Date in core data it returns an NSDate. Have you made sure you have done a clean build? Have you recently changed it from string to date?

Comment: No changes made recently. Just edited to question to show the code that pulls the data into recordDetails from the Entity Observations.

Comment: no. The code from the actual Observations class. The code that defines the property calls obsLastUpdated

Comment: Of course .... thank you. It was set as a string. And you have cleared up my question of is it actually stored as an NSDate. Great help - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define it as `NSDate`, not `NSString`:

```
MyEntity *entity = [self.recordDetails first];

NSDate *iPadDate = entity.obsLastUpdated;
```